# AS3 check if class name is

Tags: class, actionscript-3

I want to know if a Class is the main stage, in other words...

if it is "ThisName" then...

My code is:

```
MainStage = this.parent as MovieClip;
trace("scroll Stage: " + MainStage); // output: scroll Stage: [object Main_Activate]
```

but how would I write it this way?

```
if(MainStage == [object Main_Activate])
then run my code.
```

In this last example [object Main_Activate] is getting errors.

Comment: use this property `MainStage.name`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but for some reason it comes out as "root2".

Comment: So `MainStage` is second variable in your root, try this `if(MainStage.name == "root2")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`is` operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#is):

```
if (this.parent is Main_Activate)
```

Comment: you are amazing! Thanks oh AS3 master! :)